# MS Access Designview ODBC call flow

Tags: ms-access, odbc

Can any one give some idea, when we open a Designview in Ms-Access using ODBC driver, what functions are called from ODBC.

I am trying to figure out, why my designview throws an warning and the datatypes for each column prefilled with Text type.

Thx in advance to get any response

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can [turn on ODBC tracing](http://goo.gl/f947i) and examine the resulting ODBC trace file...

NOTE: you NEED to restart ALL ODBC applications (including the ODBC Administrator) in order for tracing to commence...

(The driver ODBC Driver Manager needs to get reloaded...)